# VNC client only sees a terminal

Tags: vnc, xserver

I have tightvnc server running on my Xubuntu 16.04. I can then run this command :

`xvnc4viewer 192.168.1.2:5901`

I can connect successfully to my machine but the only thing I see is this :

[image]

I guess that the reason why is because of a wrong config from my part. This is my config file :

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
#export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
# fix to make xfce work:
startxfce4 &
```

Can someone explain to me what am doing wrong on here? I want to see the desktop as I do when sitting on front of my server machine.

Answer (score 0):

Okey I got what the problem was. This is the right configuration for Xubuntu 16.04 ( which is what I am using ) :

```
#!/bin/sh
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
startxfce4 &
```

And this are the right commands :

```
tightvncserver :10 -geometry 1920x1080 ---> Start the server

tightvncserver -kill :10. ---> Kill the server

xvnc4viewer IPADDRESS:5910  ---> Connect to the server ( replace server IP address ).
```

The last command I can use it from Linux. From Mac I can simply connect using Screen Sharing app.